# Your account doesn't have access to Expo Application Services (EAS) features

Tags: expo

When I try to build to expo app getting an error saying **Your account doesn't have access to Expo Application Services (EAS) features.**

Comment: if you are using `eas build` you need to subscribe to an eas priority plan currently - while it's in feature preview it's only available to paid subscribers. http://expo.io/eas

Comment: Can i somehow build it without eas? I´m a student who can not pay 30$ a month, just for a small project..

Comment: Use `expo build` if you can. EAS isn't needed for most simple projects https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#3-start-the-build